# How to write puppeteer test with reasonable expect?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, puppeteer

Lets say I have list of objects and create button. And usually objects are created fast, there is no loading indicator or something. My cool creation test:

```
const items = await page.$$('.item');
const itemsCount = items.length;
await page.click('#create-btn');
await page.waitFor((c) => document.querySelectorAll('.item').length === c, {}, itemsCount + 1);
```

This works (might have some typos...), but as you see there is no 'expect' here,
cause this `waitFor` construction.
Is this normal?

(Currently I am rewriting non-async protractor tests to puppeteer and a bit confused that in most situations I have nothing to expect)

Comment: I see there are something to be expected. Can you write another block of your code like above one which doesn't have anything to expect?

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is give `waitFor` a timeout and then check that you got no errors:

```js
let error;
await page.waitFor(
    (c) => document.querySelectorAll('.item').length === c, {}, 
    {timeout: 500}, /*Let's give it half a sec*/
    itemsCount + 1).catch(e => error = e);
assert(error).toBeNull();
```

Comment: Y, but this doesnt look attrative

Comment: You can take at the style used in the project  https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/test/waittask.spec.js